How to apply displacement maps in shader editor to a specific vertex group
I'm experimenting with displacement maps in the Shader Editor using this guide: https://3dmodels.org/blog/displacement-maps-in-blender-tutorial/
What is the best way to apply it to only a part of the object or a specific vertex group?


What you can use instead of vertex groups is a Color Attribute, which you can reference directly in the Shader editor via the Color Attribute node.

Add a color attribute
Enter Vertex Paint mode
Paint the areas you want affected. You can use white for the areas you want affected and black for areas you want unaffected.
In your shader, add a Color Attribute node and select the Color attribute you created in step 1
Use a Vector Math node to multiply its color with the texture you're using to displace.




Thanks for taking the time for such a detailed answer! It works great :) I'm experimenting with placing the displacement node between the noise texture and the vector math node to prevent the displacement node from affecting the rest of the object.

@Ocon Ocon if the answer is correct, mark it as such
